# Avoiding upcasting in S4 R class system

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm trying to create implicitly centered/scaled matrices in R using S4 (with a view to doing this for large sparse matrices).

I can create an implicitly scaled matrix that perform correctly left and right multiplication with a vector:

```
N = 500
P = 100
X = matrix(runif(N * P), N)

setClass("scaled_matrix", contains="matrix", slots=c(scale="numeric"))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="scaled_matrix", y="numeric"),
          function(x, y) x@.Data %*% (y / x@scale))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="numeric", y="scaled_matrix"),
          function(x, y) (x %*% y@.Data) / y@scale)

get_scaled = function(A) {
  rmsd = sqrt(apply(A*A, 2, sum)/(nrow(A)-1))
  new("scaled_matrix", A, scale = rmsd)
}

X_scaled = get_scaled(X)
left_test = runif(N)
max(abs(left_test %*% X_scaled - left_test %*% scale(X, center = F))) # small, yay!
right_test = runif(P)
max(abs(X_scaled %*% right_test - scale(X, center = F) %*% right_test )) # small, yay!
```

And an implicitly centered matrix:

```
setClass("centered_matrix", 
         contains="matrix", 
         slots=c(center="numeric"))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="centered_matrix", y="numeric"),
          function(x, y) (x@.Data %*% y - as.numeric(x@center %*% y)))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="numeric", y="centered_matrix"),
          function(x, y) (x %*% y@.Data - sum(x) * y@center ))
get_centered = function(A) {
  new("centered_matrix", A, center = apply(A, 2, mean))
}

X_centered = get_centered(X)
max(abs(left_test %*% X_centered - left_test %*% scale(X, scale = F))) # small, yay!
max(abs(X_centered %*% right_test - scale(X, scale = F) %*% right_test )) # small, yay!
```

But what if I want to combine these? I thought the follow would work

```
X_centered_scaled = get_scaled(X_centered)

max(abs(left_test %*% X_centered_scaled - left_test %*% scale(X))) # not small, oh no! 
max(abs(X_centered_scaled %*% right_test - scale(X) %*% right_test )) # not small, oh no!
```

From what I can tell, the problem is that

```
class(X_centered_scaled@.Data) # should be centered_matrix but is matrix
```

i.e. when `X_centered_scaled` gets created `X_centered` gets upcast to a `matrix` instead of remaining a `centered_matrix`. Is there some way I can avoid that happening? Of course I could make a single `matrix_centered_scaled` class but I like the elegance of chaining these two together and it gives the option of just using one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out. Trick is to use an explicit `data` slot and have it be of special class `ANY`.

```
N = 500
P = 100
X = matrix(runif(N * P), N)

setClass("scaled_matrix", 
         slots=c(data = "ANY", scale="numeric"))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="scaled_matrix", y="numeric"),
          function(x, y) (x@data %*% (y / x@scale)))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="numeric", y="scaled_matrix"),
          function(x, y) ((x %*% y@data) / y@scale))

get_scaled = function(A, scale = sqrt(apply(A*A, 2, sum)/(nrow(A)-1))) {
  new("scaled_matrix", data = A, scale = scale)
}

X_scaled = get_scaled(X)
left_test = runif(N)
max(abs(left_test %*% X_scaled - left_test %*% scale(X, center = F))) # small, yay!
right_test = runif(P)
max(abs(X_scaled %*% right_test - scale(X, center = F) %*% right_test )) # small, yay!

setClass("centered_matrix",  
         slots=c(data = "ANY", center="numeric"))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="centered_matrix", y="numeric"),
          function(x, y) ( x@data %*% y - as.numeric(x@center %*% y)))
setMethod("%*%", signature(x="numeric", y="centered_matrix"),
          function(x, y) (x %*% y@data - sum(x) * y@center ))
get_centered = function(A) {
  new("centered_matrix", data = A, center = apply(A, 2, mean))
}

X_centered = get_centered(X)
max(abs(left_test %*% X_centered - left_test %*% scale(X, scale = F))) # small, yay!
max(abs(X_centered %*% right_test - scale(X, scale = F) %*% right_test )) # small, yay!

X_centered_scaled = get_scaled(X_centered, scale = apply(X, 2, sd)) # doesnt' work either

max(abs(left_test %*% X_centered_scaled - left_test %*% scale(X))) # small, yay! 
max(abs(X_centered_scaled %*% right_test - scale(X) %*% right_test )) # small, yay!
```